# Duplicate User login

Tags: php, session, session-variables

Is there an option to set Duplicate user login in PHP? When im logged in one tab and if i open another tab. It must display duplicate user or user already logged in. Kindly send me suggestions or the ways in which i can handle Duplicate user Login.

Comment: well, sure if you store user login in `_SESSION` sure you will be able to do it

Comment: @experimentX, `$_SESSION` does not get reset, once you open the page in new tab/window.. Seperate browser, is a different thing.

Comment: @Starx well, on tab sure you will get the message (session), but on different browser, i don't think that we will be able to do it.

Comment: @experimentX, Thats what I am saying. But, the OP is asking about different tabs/window according to his question. It would be help, if OP's would clarify this.

Comment: @Starx well i would agree on that.

Comment: @experiemnt,@StarX..I have used the session through all the pages. But, When im having the user logged in a tab.When i open another Tab. It must Say.. Duplicate USer login or..it must sign off from the previous tab and login into the new tab.

Comment: @Dinzy do you mean that, you want to disable login (or let logout and then login another user) in another tab?

Comment: Sorry, When i have another tab opened, it must not sign off. I mean the session must be Maintained. I think i confused a little in the previous post:)...

Answer (score 1):

Well, store the user info in `_SESSION` vars

And at the top of page

```
<?php

check_login();
```

And on `check_login()` function

```
function check_login()
{
    session_start();

    if(isset($_SESSION['is_logged']))
    {
        echo "user is already logged";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "user is not logged";
    }
}
```

I am sure if you put this on top of every page, you will be able to do it so.

This will work for same browser. But for different browser, it will not work.

Comment: @fabrik: Op was talking about a single session. Not multiple users logged in, within the same browser. But even multiple users can be done this way, by using the PHPSESSID url parameter (instead of using cookies). Check out the PHP Manual on session passing http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.idpassing.php

Comment: @Ollie as i understood he wants duplicate user login (as the title says) in the same browser, at the same time, in the same url in two different tabs.

Comment: The way i understood the question is: Duplicate = a copy of the same. And thus the same user logged in, in another tab.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you can't do it since (as far as i see) e.g. Google's dupe login can't do the trick too. When you *switch* account within Google they actually *switch* the user but you can't login with two different identities in the same browser. Maybe somehow you can trick the browser but probably that will come with a security issue.

*Btw, have you tried tricking cookies to do it?*

Update:

- build a database backend for manage (dupe) logins
- use cookies beside sessions (store a unique value to differentiate each login)
- on every page request compare your cookie > session > database to decide who requested the page

<sup>Note: this is a rough outline for the task, you'll need to take care of unique session_id's, etc.</sup>